# Climbing all the Munros as a continous round

Tags: hiking, uk, scotland-munro

I think it would be fun to climb all the [Munros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Munro) as a single long distance type route.

The wikipedia page indicates that several people have climbed all the Munros as a continuous round.

Where can I find more information about completing such a challenge?

In particular is there a standard route and how long should I expect to take?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would be worth getting a copy of ["Hamish's Mountain Walk: The First Traverse of All the Scottish Munros in One Journey"](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Hamishs-Mountain-Non-Fiction-Hamish-Brown/dp/1905207336/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1415967294&sr=1-1&keywords=9781905207336) by Hamish Brown.

Hamish Brown was the first to do the Munros on a continuous round.

If a winter attempt interests you (obviously a more serious undertaking), then Martin Moran's [The Munros in Winter](http://www.amazon.co.uk/The-Munros-Winter-Martin-Moran/dp/1905207697) is also worth getting.

Even if you are not planning on the continuous round, these books are an excellent read.

For a definitive guide on the Munros, then look for [The Munros: Scottish Mountaineering Club Hillwalkers' Guide](http://www.amazon.co.uk/The-Munros-Scottish-Mountaineering-Hillwalkers/dp/0907521940) from the Scottish Mountaineering Club.

Answer (score 8):

There are [282 Munros](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/6907/how-many-munro-revisions-has-there-been) scattered all over the 30,414 sq mi of Scotland. The average time taken to bag all the Munros is **eight years**....

The fastest munro bagging is <strike>48 days 12 hours</strike> now [39 days, 9 hours](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Munro#Fastest_round). I'd imagine you could probably double this unless your a world renowned fell runner.

There's no standard route to do it all in one go, because very few people try. You're going to need a very understanding boss!

---

If your after a easier challenge You could try the welsh 3000's (http://www.welsh3000s.co.uk/). 15 peaks in 24 hours.

Comment: I like how you link to a question that the OP'r was the accepted answer for.

Comment: The record is held by Stephen Pyke and is faster than 48 days. 39 I think.